# Greek encoding error from command line

Tags: php, email, encoding

I made a PHP script that runs from the command line and sends a message using the mail function.

```
$email_from = "support@wideservices.gr";
$email_subject = "my subject";
$email_to = "spyros@wideservices.gr";
$message="message in greek";
$headers = "From: ".$email_from;
mail($email_to,$email_subject,$message,$headers);
```

The mail is ok with Latin alphabet, but with Greek I get something like this:

[image]

I tried to use:

```
$character_set = "utf-8";
```

But without success and it is not a web page so I can't try meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will answer my own question, its working with this code and greek display correct at mail.

```
$email_from = "support@wideservices.gr";
$email_subject = "my subject";
$email_to = "spyros@wideservices.gr";
$message="message in greek";
$headers="MIME-Version: 1.0"."\n";
$headers.="Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"."\n";
$headers.="From: ".$email_from;
mail($email_to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?=', $message, $headers, '-fnoreply@domain.com');
```